# Funcion sys.intern() en python

Tags: python

-Aunque logre entender gran parte de este articulo https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/intern.html, basicamente lo que ocurre cuando se 'internalizan' las cadenas es que (por lo que entiendo) se almacenan en un lugar llamado 'tabla de cadenas internas', teniendo en cuenta esto, la pregunta es la siguiente:

```
if   (lo que dije es cierto):
   ¿Que es eso de tabla de cadenas internas?
else:
   ¿Entonces que hace la funcion sys.intern()?
```

(:-|

Comment: @abulafia te queria hacer una pregunta a ti especificamente, ya que, te noto bastante informado con respecto a python. Se que esta pregunta va a ser bastante extraña pero bueno ahi te va... ¿crees que podre encontrar absolutamente todo lo que respecta al lenguaje en la documentacion (https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/appetite.html) ? en otras palabras, ¿si me leyera toda la documentacion, podria considerar que al menos ya conozco toda la sintaxis basica y algo de avanzado?

Comment: Respecto a la pregunta que me haces, la documentación de Python es excelente. ¡Demasiado excelente me atrevo a decir! Su documentación es muy extensa y cubre muchos niveles, incluso detalles _demasiado_ avanzados. Por supuesto que si te la lees y _comprendes todo_, dominarás la sintaxis y los entresijos (aunque el verdadero dominio de su uso te lo dará el usarlo y hacer muchas cosas con él). Pero si quieres algo más accesible (y también muy exhaustivo y riguroso) a mi me gusta mucho el libro "Fluent python" de Luciano Ramalho

Comment: Aprovecho para decir que me gustan mucho tus preguntas. Siempre das con detalles que no son obvios, y que demuestran (creo) que vas entendiendo lo que haces. También muestran que no te gusta dejar pasar algo sin haberlo entendido a fondo. Eso es bueno, pero no olvides que escribiendo código y cometiendo errores también se aprende mucho! Y respondiendo a preguntas de otros usuarios!

Comment: @abulafia Si, es algo que me caracteriza, me desepera el no entender algo de mi codigo y es por lo mismo que tiendo a aprender las cosas bastante rapido, por lo menos, cuando empeze con mi primer lenguaje (Pascal hace unos 5 meses) tuve que leerme primero muchos libros de hardware, no entendia como era que ese 'hola mundo' se habia impreso por pantalla... de igual forma quiero agradecerte, literalmente eres el primer usuario que es ligeramente amable en SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación es bastante clara.

Para responder directamente a tu pregunta:

> ¿Que es eso de tabla de cadenas internas?

Es una colección de cadenas manejada *tras bambalinas* por python. En esta colección, todas las cadenas existen una única vez y cuando llamas a `intern()` con una cadena que ya existe, en lugar de crear una nueva cadena, te devuelve la referencia a la cadena ya existente.

Podemos imaginar que esto está implementado como una lista ordenada alfabéticamente, de manera que determinar si una cadena existe para insertar un nuevo registro se pueda hacer muy rápidamente.

Por otro lado, python va a *internalizar* cadenas que sean cortas (o no tanto) de manera automática.

En la documentación de [`sys.intern`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern) podemos leer:

> Ingresa string en la tabla de cadenas de caracteres «internadas» y retorna la cadena de caracteres interna, que es string en sí misma o una copia. Internar cadenas de caracteres es útil para obtener un poco de rendimiento en la búsqueda de diccionario: si las claves en un diccionario están internadas y la clave de búsqueda está interna, las comparaciones de claves (después del hash) se pueden realizar mediante una comparación de punteros en lugar de una comparación de cadenas. Normalmente, los nombres utilizados en los programas de Python se internan automáticamente, y los diccionarios utilizados para contener los atributos de módulo, clase o instancia tienen claves internas.
>
> Las cadenas de caracteres internas no son inmortales; debe mantener una referencia al valor de retorno de intern() para beneficiarse de él.

Puedes valerte de la función [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#id) para obtener la dirección de memoria de una variable, entonces, puedes ver el funcionamiento de esto con algo como:

```
import sys

a = "Dato"
b = "Dato"
c = "Dato de cadena un poco más largo que será internado en versiones modernas de python pero no en otras más antiguas"
d = "Dato de cadena un poco más largo que será internado en versiones modernas de python pero no en otras más antiguas"
e = sys.intern("Dato de cadena un poco más largo que siempre será internado tanto en versiones modernas de python como en otras más antiguas")
f = sys.intern("Dato de cadena un poco más largo que siempre será internado tanto en versiones modernas de python como en otras más antiguas")

print("Dirección de a ", id(a))
print("Dirección de b ", id(b))
print("a is b ", a is b)

print("Dirección de c ", id(c))
print("Dirección de d ", id(d))
print("c is d ", c is d)

print("Dirección de e ", id(e))
print("Dirección de f ", id(f))
print("e is f ", e is f)
```

Cuando pruebo con python 3.9, obtengo esta salida:

```
Dirección de a  139810578508016
Dirección de b  139810578508016
a is b  True
Dirección de c  139810578600560
Dirección de d  139810578600560
c is d  True
Dirección de e  139810579126320
Dirección de f  139810579126320
e is f  True
```

Como puedes ver, todas las cadenas han sido internadas (incluso las que no tienen una llamada explícita a `intern()`).

La principal ventaja de esto, es que al hacer una comparación de igualdad, tal como `if (a==b)`, en lugar de tener que comparar caracter por caracter, simplemente se compara la dirección de memoria de ambas variables (una comparación de punteros), lo cual resulta en una ejecución más eficiente (aunque la diferencia en tiempo es imperceptible en CPU's modernos).

En versiones anteriores de python, las variables `c` y `d` podrían residir en direcciones de memoria distintas, así que una comparación de igualdad obligará a realizar una comparación caracter por caracter.