# Mutabilidad vs Inmutabilidad (Python)

Tags: python

A traves de esta pregunta, me gustaria saber cual es la difencia entre la *mutabilidad* y la *inmutabilidad* en `Python`, mas alla del hecho de que *unos se pueden modificar y otros no*. La pregunta la establezco por dos razones:

1-Me causa bastante curiosidad el hecho de que algunos objetos iterables en Python, solo admiten objetos *inmutables* (diccionarios, conjuntos, etc ...). Puedo llegar a entender en el caso de los diccionarios que sea por ejemplo para que el programador no cambie accidentalemnte la clave de algun valor, y que ulteriormente no sepa por que no puede acceder al diccionario, pero que me dices de los conjuntos, por que no admiten objetos mutables?

2-En una parte de la [documentacion](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dic), justo al principio de la explicacion de los diccionarios), dice lo siguiente ...

> Las claves de un diccionario pueden ser casi de cualquier tipo.
> Los valores que no son hashable, como por ejemplo valores que
> contengan listas, diccionarios u otros tipo mutables (que son
> comparados por valor, no por referencia) no se pueden usar como claves."

Esto quiere decir que los objetos mutables se comparan por valor y no por referencia, y que los inmutables hacen exactamente lo contrario . Y esto tiene sentido cuando vemos el comportamiento de Python en asignacion de valores. Cuando se tratan de cadenas, Python comprueba si el valor esta en la [tabla de cadenas internas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443680/funcion-sys-intern-en-python), y esto lo podemos ver en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> b = 'foo'
>>> a is b
True
```

Sin embargo, si lo intentamos con cualquier otro tipo de dato, mutable o inmutable, no funciona ... (Notese que de hecho, cuando las cadenas son muy largas, el interprete no comprueba la existencia de cadenas subyacentes)

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> a is b
True (ver modificacion)


>>> a = set([1])
>>> b = set([1])
>>> a is b
False
```

Esta bastante claro que, lo que ocurrio con las cadenas se deba tan solo a una simple casualidad, (o que Python solo busque cadenas ya existentes cuando la que se busca es corta??), ya que, esto solo ocurre de vez en cuando con cadenas y enteros (ver modificacion). El caso esta en lo siguiente: si los objetos inmutables se comparan por referencia, por que no hay un sistema de paso de referencias mayor, en otras palabras, por que no se comprueba mas seguido la existencia de objetos subyacentes, precisamente para que la comparacion por referencia se mas *exacta*.

Sin mencionar, que aquello de que los objetos inmutables se comparan a traves de referencias y no valores, no esta del todo claro...

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> b = (1,2)
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
>>> 


>>> a = frozenset([1,2])
>>> b = frozenset([1,2])
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
```

**Finalmente la pregunta seria**: *cual es la diferencia entre la adminnistracion de objetos mutables e inmutables en Python mas haya de que algunos se pueden modificar y otros no??*

**Modificacion:** en el ejemplo de los enteros, `a is b` ya que el valor `10` esta *'precreado'* (al igual que todos los numeros del -5 al 256) , por lo tanto al decir `a = 10`, `a` va a apuntar al `10` que ya existe y lo mismo ocurre con `b`, lo que genera que `a is b`([referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306662/por-qu%c3%a9-el-operador-is-no-funciona-para-comparar-valores/306705#306705)).

Comment: hay un error en lo que mencionas de `a is b` cuando su valor es `10`, pues python tiene ya creado algunos de estos datos por lo que siempre será `True`, si cambias su valor por `1000` en ambos casos y haces lo mismo, veras que te da `False`

Comment: puedes ver esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306705/183782)

Comment: @Christian ciertamente ... Gracias maquina

Comment: creo que la respuesta es sencilla, python crea los objetos, pues `a` es un objeto que apunta a su valor y `b` es otro objeto, `is` compara a donde apunta, y pues `a` no apunta a `b`

Comment: creo que daré una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el principal problema es conforme a la definición de categorías de variables y su diferencias. Voy a intentar concentrarme principalmente en las secuencias debido a que suelen ser el tipo de variables en las cuales más diferencias puedes encontrar.

Aunque inicialmente no responden tus preguntas, creo que definir estos conceptos te puede ayudar a tener una visión más completa del panorama y a poder delimitar cada categoría y que ventajas pueden implicar.

> **Nota.** Al final se presenta las respuestas a las preguntas planteadas

Las secuencias se pueden clasificar a partir de varios parámetros, uno de esos parametros es el tipo de variables que puede contener, a partir de este se definen dos tipos de secuencias:

1. **Secuencias contenedoras (Container sequences)**. Pueden almacenar objetos de distintos tipos.Algunos ejemplos de este tipo de secuencias son: list, tuple, etc.
2. **Secuencias planas (Flat sequences)**. Permite almacenar objetos de un mismo tipo. Algunos ejemplos de este tipo de secuencias son: bytes, str, array, etc.

A partir de esta clasificación lo único que se intenta remarcar es el hecho de los tipos **flat sequences** solo pueden contener un tipo de objeto, es decir, el tipo str solo contiene caracteres mientras un **container sequences** puede contener en un mismo objeto algunas estructuras anidadas, cadenas, enteros, etc. La forma en como se logra que un secuencia pueda ser de tipo **container sequence** es conceptualmente a través de una estructura similar a un array de apuntadores (en C), es decir, que una lista es un array, donde el primer índice apunta al primer objeto y es aquí donde se marca principalmente la diferencia de rendimiento entre estos dos tipos de sequencias.

1. Para acceder a un objeto dentro de un **container sequences** primero hay que leer la dirección de memoria que se encuentra en el indice referenciado, una vez obtenida la dirección de memoria, hay que hacer referencia a ella para obtener realmente el objeto que nos importa
2. En el casos de **flat sequences**, los valores son directamente guardados en el indice del array, es decir que solo hay que ir al indice del array para saber cual es el valor del objeto que nos importa, no es necesario el paso intermedio de leer una dirección de memoria extra.

Hasta este momento y debido al funcionamiento antes mencionado, las **flat sequences** tienen principalmente dos ventajas:

1. Una **flat sequence** guarda los valores como tal, no necesita guardar información extra para poder hacer referencia a cualquier tipo de objeto (como es en el caso de **container sequences**), esto se traduce a menor costo de memoria.
2. Las computadoras modernas generalmente hacen uso de varios niveles de caché basados en el principio de localidad, de manera muy reducida quiere decir que cuando lees información de memoria, esta lectura no solo trae exactamente lo que quieres, si no que ademas trae bloques o páginas de memoria que contienen información que se encuentra cerca de la que estas intentando obtener, esto es extremadamente útil cuando tienes array debido a que los array abarcan direcciones de memoria adjuntas que se traduce en que cuando lees un índice, posiblemente tengas los valores de sus índices vecinos en caché. En el caso de las **flat sequences**, estas son beneficiadas completamente por estos mécanismos, mientras las **container sequences** se ven perjudicadas por que dentro de cada índice tienen un puntero que lleva al valor, y este valor muy posiblemente no este cercano en cuanto a direcciones de memoria, razón por la cual puede ser menos posible que este en caché.

Marcando estas principales diferencias, existen también la clasificación conforme a la mutabilidad de las estructuras.

1. **Secuencias mutables**. Pueden ser modificadas. Ejemplo: list, array, etc.
2. **Secuencias inmutables**. No pueden ser modificadas. Ejemplo: str, tuple, etc.

La principal diferencia ademas del hecho de que pueden o no pueden ser modificadas es en su funcionamiento interno, por ejemplo la comparación entre list y tuple es conforme a su rendimiento, y esto puede ser expresado en varios sentidos:

1. Las tuplas no tienen que reservar memoria extra debido a que no pueden ser modificadas, en cambio las list deben tener un colchón de memoria para amortizar  la acción de expandirse.
2. Hay optimizaciones en el bytecode generado por las **tuple** que no se encuentran en las variables de tipo **list**.
3. Al realizar una copia con `float(f)`, se retorna una referencia al mismo objeto.

A partir de lo anterior, quiero remarcar que la inmutabilidad no solo se da en secuencias, también puede hablarse de variables de tipo númerico, sin embargo la comparación o las ventajas que puede presentarse con este tipo de dato son muy específicas de cada circunstancia, realmente no es que estrictamente alguna categoría se compare por referencia y otra por valor.

A partir de lo antes expresado, voy a empezar a aclarar algunos puntos que mencionabas.

> 1-Me causa bastante curiosidad el hecho de que algunos objetos iterables en Python, solo admiten objetos inmutables (diccionarios, conjuntos, etc ...).

Esto no es del todo cierto, los diccionarios y conjuntos no aceptan solo objetos inmutables como llaves, en realidad cualquier instancia de una clase definida por un usuario puede ser utilizada como llave y esta no tiene que ser inmutable. El requisito para que un objeto puede ser utilizado como llave es que sea hashable, esto significa que:

1. El objeto debe implementar el dunder method `__hash__` que retorna el hash code que representa al objeto. En caso de que sea una instancia de una clase definida por el usuario, este método retorna el valor del la función `id` por defecto, es decir, la dirección de memoria del objeto.
2. El objeto debe implmenetar el dunder method `__eq__` que debe retornar un valor booleano que determine si es igual a otro objeto. Cada pareja de objetos que retorne `True` al realizar una comparación de igualdad con `__eq__`, también debería retornar el mismo hash code en sus métodos `__hash__`. En caso de que sea una instancia de una clase definida por el usuario, este método retorna el valor del la función `id` por defecto, es decir, la dirección de memoria del objeto.

La necesidad de que ambos métodos esten definidos se da principalmente por como funcionan los diccionarios y el tratamiento de colisiones en sus hash code.

> **Nota.** Claramente no tendría mucho sentido definir una clase Persona que utiliza como hash el hash del campo nombre y que posteriormente modifica este campo e intenta buscar el objeto en el diccionario, creo que en ese sentido se define la inmutabilidad en este caso.

Por último y no menos importante...

> Esto quiere decir que los objetos mutables se comparan por valor y no por referencia, y que los inmutables hacen exactamente lo contrario . Y esto tiene sentido cuando vemos el comportamiento de Python en asignacion de valores. Cuando se tratan de cadenas, Python comprueba si el valor esta en la tabla de cadenas internas, y esto lo podemos ver en el siguiente ejemplo:

La respuesta es no, independientemente si la variable es mutable o inmutable, se tiene dos métodos de comparación.

1. `__eq__`. Llamado mediante el operador `==` y comprueba generalmente la igualdad de los objetos conforme a los valores que contiene
2. `is`. Compara dos objetos pero mediante su referencia (dirección de memoria).

En resumen se puede decir que una variable no es un valor o un objeto, es una etiqueta o enlace a un objeto, varias etiquetas pueden apuntar al mismo objeto y cuando no existen etiquetas apuntando a un objeto o las únicas etiquetas son de objetos que se estan apuntando entre ellos mismos, entonces estos objetos son eliminados por el intérprete mediante el `garbage collector`.

Entonces, ambos tipos de objetos se pueden comparar mediante valor o mediante su referencia(dirección de memoria) o etiqueta, la razón por la cual obtienes este resultado:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> a is b
True (ver modificacion)
```

Es por optimizaciones que hace python, estas dependen de la versión de python y son definidas al estilo de... los primeros 256 números son cacheados en memoria, razón por la cual, cualquier variable (etiqueta que apunte a ellos) va hacer referencia al mismo objeto en memoria, es por eso que la comparación con `is` es verdadera.

Una optimización similar ocurre con las cadenas pero en ambos casos no deberías tomar como premisa que estas optimizaciones siempre son realizadas, puede variar entre versiones.

Comment: NI siquiera la he leido toda y ya empieza a gustarme, muy buena respuesta ...

Comment: Si, es un tema bastante interesante y amplio. Si te interesa profundizar y ver un vista más completa de estos tipos de detalles, te recomiendo el libro `Fluent Python, 2nd Edition`, su editorial tiene una plataforma en línea que te permite leer el libro con una prueba gratuita.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a hacer algo rápido, primero hay que saber que `is` compara si la variable *apunta* al mismo objeto, mas no si contienen el mismo valor.

Cada vez que asignas un valor a una variable, Python crea el objeto (mutable o inmutable)

En el caso de los objetos inmutables, como su nombre lo dice, no podran cambiar su valor, si tenemos una variabl `b=10` y luego le sumamos `1` python no reemplaza la variable `b` a `11`, sino que crea otro objeto y luego suma los valores `10+1` y finalmente crea otro objeto y le asigna el valor `11`, lo que no pasa con los objetos mutables. Un ejemplo muy común es reemplazar una posición de un string, pero al ser inmutable, esto te dará un error.

```py
string = "texto"
string[0] = "T"
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

En caso de los datos mutables si se puede hacer eso, como por ejemplo las listas:

```
lista = ["H","o","l","a"]
lista[0] = "h"

print(lista)
#salida-> ['h', 'o', 'l', 'a']
```

Bueno ahora vamos a ver lo que pasa con los datos inmutables, según tu ejemplo:

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> b = (1,2)

>>> a is b
False
```

Esto es totalmente correcto y te lo muestro con el siguiente grafico

[image: variables_mutables]

Se crean los dos objetos cada uno con su respectivo valor, ninguna de las variables apunta al mismo objeto, por lo que al usar `is` te devolverá `False` pero al usar el operador de compracion `==` el resultado será `True`. Podemos hacer que la variable apunte al mismo objeto asiendo la asignacion correspondiente

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> b = (1,2)
>>> a = b
>>> a is b
>>> True
```

Pero con las cadenas pasa algo diferente pues aquí entra en juego, la *tabla de cadenas internas*, esta es como una *lista* o *contenedor* que almacena los stings creados y creas otra variable cuyo valor se encuentra aquí, se te devolverá la referencia de este valor. Miremos el grafico

[image: explicacion_tabla_de_cadenas_internas]

Si creamos las variables `a,b,c` donde `a="foo"`, `b="bar"` y `c="foo"` todas estas cadenas se iran almacenando en la *tabla de cadenas internas* donde si ya existe una cadena con el valor que se le asigna a otra, solo se hace que la nueva variable apunte a la misma cadena, al final las variables `a` y `c` apuntan al mismo objeto y por tal razón.

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> b = 'foo'
>>> a is b
True
```

Comment: No explicas por que las cadenas con una longitud mayor no se almacenan en la tabla de cadenas internas (o mas bien, no se comprueba si ya existe alli). Tampoco explicas por que en la documentacion dice que los inmutables se comparan por referencias si las referencias nunca se pasan de un puntero a otro (al menos que se haga explicitamente), ni tampoco se comparan por referencia realmente por referencia (el ultimo ejemplo de la publicacion, los valores son iguales y las referencias son distintas). Por otro lado, lo del is ya lo sabia, no hacia falta explicarlo ...

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta igualmente, creia que siempre se comprobaba la existencia de un objeto ya declarado cuando el objeto es inmutable

Comment: explique lo que pude, tal vez haya mas respuestas